# Find the common difference

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The 5th term of an arithmetic sequence is 15 and the 1st term is 10 times the 7th term. 
How can I find the first term and the common difference.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You get a "closE" for effort. Here on MSE context is what keeps a question afloat - it may be the problem's source, or attempts at it. And welcome to the Grand Stack Exchange.

Comment: Hint : the $n$th term of the arithmetic sequence $(u_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ which starts at $u_{0} \in \mathbb{R}$, with increment $r \in \mathbb{R}$ is given by : $u_{n} = u_{0} + nr$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$a_n=a_1+(n−1)d$ is the general term of AP

If we take the 5th term
$15=a+4d$
we divide the equation with $a$
it becomes         $\frac{15}{a}=1+\frac{4d}{a}$   .....[1]

AGAIN if we take the $7th$ term
the form is   $\text{7th term}=a+6d$

we know $a=10a+60d$
from here we get  $\frac da=\frac{-3}{20}$

putting the value in equation [1]
we get $a=37.5$ 
similarly we can get $d$.

Comment: The name of the OP matches with yours!!;-)

Comment: so what can i do

Comment: do u like the solution??

Comment: Yeah...quite good...

Comment: Good answer...(+1 vote)...

Answer (score 1):

we get $$a_5=a_1+4d=15$$ and $$a_1=10a_7=10(a_1+6d)$$
now you must solve the equation system

Comment: $a_1=37.5, d=-5.625$